# Как выровнять заголовок с помощью flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

Как сделать так, чтобы заголовок был по центру страницы с помощью flex?

Вот мой код:

```css
.title_conteiner{
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #202020;
  text-align: center;
}

.date_content{
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 178px;
}

.date{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #aed2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_conteiner">
  <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
  <div class="date_content">
    <p class="date">26 ноября 2021 | 16:55</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам принципиально надо, чтобы заголовок и дата были на одной строке, то никак, так как текст позиционируется по центру относительно ширины блока, только если вы не укажите заголовку ширину 100%, можно дополнительно вычесть ширину блока с датой, если Вы её указали.

```css
.title_conteiner{
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #202020;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 178px);
}

.date_content{
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 178px;
}

.date{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #aed2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_conteiner">
  <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
  <div class="date_content">
    <p class="date">26 ноября 2021 | 16:55</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вообще я бы рекомендовал Вам перенести заголовок и дату на разные строки. Тогда можно будет более грамотно их распределить.

```css
.title_conteiner {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #202020;
  text-align: center;
}

.date_content {
  max-width: 178px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.date {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #aed2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_conteiner">
  <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
  <div class="date_content">
    <p class="date">26 ноября 2021 | 16:55</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хотя и вёрстку бы немного переделал, не правильно это, на мой взгляд, растягивать тег `p`.

```css
.title_conteiner {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #202020;
}

.date_content {
  text-align: right;
}

.date {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #aed2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_conteiner">
  <div class="block-title">
    <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date_content">
    <p class="date">26 ноября 2021 | 16:55</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если хотите всё же разместить на одной строке, то можно из отступа сверху вычесть расстояние необходимое для поднятия блока с датой. Данный способ не совсем удобный, так как он съедает часть ширины блока под заголовок, он не будет 100%, да и необходимо высчитывать сколько Вам подымать блок с датой на разных ширинах экрана.

```css
.title_conteiner {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block-title {
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 270px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #202020;
}

.date_content {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.date {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #aed2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_conteiner">
  <div class="block-title">
    <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date_content">
    <p class="date">26 ноября 2021 | 16:55</p>
  </div>
</div>
```